# Pass Angular Model to SailsJs

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

I trying to pass a form via $http.post from AngularJS to Sailsjs

**My Sails Controller**

```
  create: function(req, res) {
    console.log("req: "+req.param('user.firstName')); 

    res.send(req.param('user.firstName'));

   },
```

**My Angular Controller**

```
    function RegisterController($scope, $http) {

        $scope.submit = function(){
            console.log($scope.user.firstName); // works fine so far 
            $http.post('/user/create', $scope.user)
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  console.log("success");
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  console.log("error");
                });

        }

    }
```

If I call my sails function like so /user/create?user.firstName=myFirstName its works fine. But if I try to read my passed data if I pass from angular. I don't know. I can't read the parm...

Someone any idea or a small example?

Cheers awesome community =)

Comment: not really sure about this. please try console.log(req.params.all());  or console.log(req.param('firstName')); ... we don't use sails anymore, so i am maybe a bit outdated ;)

Comment: console.log(req.param('firstName') works. Thanks for that!!!

Comment: req.params is for name route. use req.query. read express doc http://expressjs.com/api.html

Comment: @wayne Not true.  `req.param` will get data from the route, the parsed body, and the query string (in that order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're posting the `$scope.user` object to your route, so it won't be namespaced under `user`.  If the `$scope.user` contains, for example:

```
{firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}
```

then they would be available in your controller action as `req.param('firstName')` and `req.param('lastName')`.

If you were to post the *entire* `$scope` object to `/user/create` (don't do this!), then you would be able to access `req.param('user').firstName`, `req.param('user').lastName`, etc.  You still wouldn't be able to access things like `req.param('user.firstName')`, though; those are Angular expressions but they don't work server-side.

Comment: BTW, if you need to fully bind your user model (or any other model) to angular, you can try angular-sails-bind (https://github.com/diegopamio/angular-sails-bind) I've just released to the world a couple of minutes ago :). I made it for my own project and then decided to put it as a separated library so everybody could benefit and I could have my first experience developing a bower package.

I hope it could help you.

BTW: it works with sails 0.10 (as some things, like topic names had changed since 0.9). If you need to make it work with 0.9, just let me know and I'll happy to help.